# Using Tree like structure in python

Tags: python, data-structures

**Background**

I have a bucket on s3 called `sample-level-test`. It contains folders for each day such as `2020-10-08`, `2020-10-09` and `2020-10-10`.

Each date folder contains many folders that are id of a player like `2020-10-08/31001457373383`, `2020-10-08/31001457373383` etc.

The folders `31001457373383` and `31001457373383` are player level folders and each such player level folder contains 3 files.

**My Code**

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(name="sample-level-test")

 for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
     print(my_bucket_object)
```

**My code sample output**

```
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='sample-level-test', key='2020-10-08/31001457373383/player-DNA.json')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='sample-level-test', key='2020-10-08/31001457373383/player-DNA.csv')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='sample-level-test', key='2020-10-08/31001457373383/player-DNA_report.tsv')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='sample-level-test', key='2020-10-09/31001461776686/player-DNA.json')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='sample-level-test', key='2020-10-09/31001461776686/player-DNA.csv')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='sample-level-test', key='2020-10-09/31001461776686/player-DNA_report.tsv')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='sample-level-test', key='2020-10-10/310014685532736/player-DNA.json')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='sample-level-test', key='2020-10-10/310014685532736/player-DNA.csv')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='sample-level-test', key='2020-10-10/310014685532736/player-DNA_report.tsv')
```

**My Problem**

I am trying to create a tiny service that given some number X. It will return the X total player keys in the bucket by oldest date.

For example if X = 1 then my output should be `['2020-10-08/31001457373383']`.

For example if X = 2 then my output should be `['2020-10-08/31001457373383', '2020-10-09/31001461776686']`.

**My Current Approach**

Currently i loop through the entire output which is essentially the list of all objects in the bucket and i parse out individual date folders.
Then i make check each date folder and get keys until i hit X.

I think my approach is flawed and very slow. I am wondering if there is a better way to approach this. I know in Java there is tree data structures where i can store this kind of directory output in a tree format and it would be fast to retrieve info if needed. Is there something similar i can use in python?

Comment: is it essential to tree like structure? It seems like your output is already sorted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your structure is all the same, you can split the keys, remove duplicates and get your answer by slicing the resulting list

```
keys_list = ['2020-10-08/31001457373383/player-DNA.json',
'2020-10-08/31001457373383/player-DNA.csv',
'2020-10-08/31001457373383/player-DNA_report.tsv',
'2020-10-09/31001461776686/player-DNA.json',
'2020-10-09/31001461776686/player-DNA.csv',
'2020-10-09/31001461776686/player-DNA_report.tsv',
'2020-10-10/310014685532736/player-DNA.json',
'2020-10-10/310014685532736/player-DNA.csv',
'2020-10-10/310014685532736/player-DNA_report.tsv']

x=2
new_list = list(set([s.split('/player')[0] for s in keys_list]))
new_list.sort()
answer_list = new_list[0:x]
```

Output for x=2

```
['2020-10-08/31001457373383', '2020-10-09/31001461776686']
```